# ¿rutas en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo los modelos `Player`, `Team` y `PlayerTeam`; `PlayerTeam` es la tabla del medio que forma la relación de muchos a muchos entre `Player` y `Team`.

player.rb:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord   
  has_many :player_teams   
  has_many :teams , through: :player_teams

  before_save do
    self.numero_goals = 0
    self.reputation = 0
    self.plays_win = 0
    self.plays_lose = 0 
  end  
end
```

team.rb:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :player_teams, dependent: :destroy  
  has_many :players, through: :player_teams  
  has_many :team_battles, dependent: :destroy  
  has_many :battles, through: :team_battles 
end
```

player_team.rb:

```
class PlayerTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Las rutas actualmente lo tengo así:

```
resources :players do
  resources :player_teams
end

resources :teams do
  resources :player_teams
end
```

Quiero saber cómo puedo organizarlo de la mejor manera para que, una vez que se cree un `Player`, este pueda escoger un `Team` o crearlo, para así guardarle automáticamente en la tabla `PlayerTeam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La asociación que estás utilizando te sirve tanto para escoger como para crear un `Team`. La organización de las rutas que propones me parece más complicada de lo necesario, pues utilizando `resources` para cada modelo sería más que suficiente; por ejemplo:

```
resources :players
resources :teams
```

Para crear un nuevo `Player` y elegir un `Team` para el, simplemente harías algo así:

Vista (e.g. *player.new.html*):

```
<%= form_for @player do |f| %>
  <!-- campos para crear el `Player` -->
  <%= collection_select(:team, :name, Team.all, :id, :name)
<% end %>
```

Controlador (e.g. *players_controller.rb*):

```
def create
  @player  = Player.new(player_params)
  @player << Team.find(params[:team_id])

  if @player.save
    # acciones para guardado exitoso
  else
    # acciones para manejo de errores
  end
end

private
def player_params
  params.request(:player).permit(...)
end
```

Para crear un `Team` harías lo mismo, pero en lugar de utilizar un `collection_select` deberías utilizar campos para enviar los datos del `Team` y, en el controlador utilizarías algo similar a `Team.new(team_params)` en lugar de `Team.find(:team_id)`.

Tu pregunta es muy abierta, por lo tanto la respuesta no puede ser muy detallada sin asumir de más. Recomiendo que tomes este ejemplo y lo adaptes a tu código y, en caso que encuentres errores específicos, puedas publicar una pregunta más detallada.

Comment: gracias.Lo estaré implementando